# Django South migrate model file backwards

Tags: django, django-south

I'm using South for migrations. I can't seem to work out if South can also be used to amend the models themselves. Upon returning to a previous model state, am I to manually alter the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

South does not modify your `models.py`. It only alters the database. It is generally used in conjunction with version control software (such as git) that would allow you to revert your `models.py` to match the south migration.

Comment: It sounds like a "must have" recommendation to be in the South tutorial page. I only realized I should had commited every change made in models.py after messing up my database.

Answer (score 0):

> am I to manually alter the code?

Yes. South altering models code seems for me not like a good idea. Only you know what where exact code changes because of your migration.

And for me, I performed backwards migration couple times and in most cases didn't wanted the model to change to previous state.

Comment: "didn't wanted the model to change to previous state." So, your models doesn't match you database schema. Isn't this a problem to you?